# MySQL: logging queries which would execute without using indexes

Tags: mysql, index-tuning

I am trying to use `log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1` to find queries which are not executing optimally on a MySQL server. However, I find the resulting log file of rather limited value. Apparently, queries are logged whenever the optimizer really decided not to use an index as a criterion in a WHERE clause. And **not** if they truly have no indexes matching the filtered columns.

So given a table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id_test`   int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `some_text`  varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `some_more_text` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_test`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

a query `SELECT id_test from test where id_test != 69` would be logged to the *slow log* because of not using indexes (the optimizer has decided that a table scan is more efficient as not much could be won by using an index) but `SELECT id_test from test where id_test = 69` would not.

I would expect the behavior of the latter query in the first case as well since the index is present. As is, it makes troubleshooting missing indexes rather tiresome. Ideas on how to approach this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you expected `log_queries_not_using_indexes=1` to not log queries that didn't *use* an index. The idea of the setting is to see which queries are getting run on your server that could be ideal candidates for optimization. For your example:

```
SELECT id_test from test where id_test != 69
```

Unless you change the requirements of the query, there's not much you can do. Of course it's faster to do a full scan and return all rows that don't match that `id_test` value.

As for ideas on how to approach analysis:

- You can set [`min_examined_row_limit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_min_examined_row_limit) to a higher value. If, for example, you want to exclude queries that examine less than 5,000 rows, set this variable to 5000. This is useful to reduce the 'noise' in the slow query log.
- You can use a tool called [`pt-query-digest`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) with the `--review` option to review your slow queries. The tool allows you to store your review history so you don't repeat work on the same query during analysis:

  > It won’t show you queries you’ve already reviewed. A query is considered to be already reviewed if you’ve set a value for the reviewed_by column. (If you want to see queries you’ve already reviewed, use the --report-all option.)

  It also has the added benefit of storing a history of the queries that get logged in your slow query. Who wouldn't love historical evidence of improving your queries?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I basically wanted to only have queries listed for tables where I actually might consider adding an index. MySQL's behavior is rather counterintuitive in this respect as it even would log stuff where indexes cannot be added any more (because they are there already). But I guess I could use min_examined_row_limit as a workaround.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. I'm not sure how MySQL would intuitively know indexes couldn't be added anymore. Many of the times if the optimizer deems it better to not use any index, that doesn't mean the query can't be tuned. But sometimes the query can't be tuned. That's where the history aspect of pt-query-digest comes in handy, to skip those queries from further review.

Comment: After pondering around with pt-query-digest I found it extremely useful for exactly the reasons you've cited. Thanks for that.